# 7 concerts on 7 days per week - probability that on one day there are two concerts

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> We consider 7 concerts which can be scheduled throughout a week (7 days). What's the probability that there are at least two concerts on one day if each day is equally probable to be chosen?

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle my approach is as follows:

$$\sum_{k=1}^7{7 \choose k} {13-k \choose7-k}(-1)^{k-1}$$ 
are all possible ways of scheduling the concerts on 6 days, on 5 days, 4 days and so on...

All possible combinations of scheduling the concerts on all 7 days sum up to: ${13 \choose 7}$. As all combinations are equally probable we have a Laplace Experiment and the probability of having at least two concerts a day is:
$$1-\left(\sum_{k=1}^7\frac{{7 \choose k} {13-k \choose7-k}(-1)^{k-1}}{{13 \choose 7}}\right).$$

Is this correct?

I am a little bit confused because the official solution  is:
$$1-\left(\sum_{k=1}^7{7 \choose k} \left(1-\frac{k}{7}\right)^7(-1)^{k-1}\right)$$ However, this would imply that the concerts are distinguishable. But in my opinion the question does not clearly mention this because we are only interested in the possibility that at least any two concerts should take place on one day. What do you think? Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is flawed.  Do not forget, you may only talk about probability as a ratio of good events over total events in the case that the outcomes in the sample space are *equally likely to occur*.  There are two possibilities when playing the lottery, you win or you lose, but you don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  I cannot stress that enough.  By using stars-and-bars to try to count the number of ways of distributing concerts, those outcomes are not equally likely to occur.  It is far more likely for a concert to occur one per day than it is to have all on the same day.

Comment: That being said, I don't like the official solution either.  Sure, it looks like it could be correct, but there should be no reason to have written it like that.  You could get the same result by just subtracting the number of ways of having one concert per day... $1-\frac{7!}{7^7}$.  That being said, it looks like they subtracted from $1$ when they didn't need to.

Comment: @JMoravitz, however if I am only interested in the number of ways to schedule at least 2 concerts on one day we get: $${13 \choose 7}-\left(\sum_{k=1}^7 {7 \choose k} {13-k \choose7-k}(-1)^{k-1}\right).$$ Right?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "ways" of scheduling concerts.  If you cannot tell the concert apart because all that rap music sounds the same to you, then sure.  If you happen to be a huge fan and notice that the musicians singing in each or the setlist in each vary, then you can have many more than that.  The point is that under any reasonable assumptions as to how you randomly assign the concerts to the days, those ways counted by stars-and-bars are *not* equally likely to occur.

Comment: Yes I meant that you cannot distinguish between the concerts. I think my problem was that I got confused with just counting all the possibilities and actually calculating the probability.